# Matplotlib scatter plot graphs fine the second time but not the first time with tkinter. How does this happen?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I was trying to go for a user-inputted csv file and the selecting of # of dots on the scatter plots. It seems to work fine and display the graph correctly after I close out of the window the first time, but it doesn't display it correctly the first time.

First time running the scatterplot after executing the program:

[image]

Second time and onwards running the scatterplot with correct # of dots:

[image]

Whenever I clicked the select file button and selected the file, it would add a new blank window instead of the intended graph. The second time around it worked

This is the code to the function I wrote as a command to be called by a button. Everything else runs as intended except the scatterplot.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def makeScatterPlot():
  df = get_csv()

  new2 = tk.Toplevel(win)
  new2.geometry('400x400')
  new2.title('Scatter Plot')

  dataInd1 = 5
  dataInd2 = 6
  numberOfRows = int(scatterInput.get())

  col1 = df.iloc[:numberOfRows, dataInd1]
  col2 = df.iloc[:numberOfRows, dataInd2]

  data1 = []
  data2 = []

  for x in col1: 
    data1.append(x)
  for y in col2: 
    data2.append(y)

  plt.scatter(data1, data2)

  fig1 = plt.figure(2)
  canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=new2)
  plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
  plot_widget.pack()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're plotting in a tk window rather than using the normal windows created by matplotlib?

Comment: I was using the tkinter windows because the bar graph was not opening when I was trying to apply to a matplotlib window. The scatterplot has the same outcome so I added a new window as a solution.

Comment: If you run the simple example from [this link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html), does a plot open?